# geocoding google maps api return different place_id

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Geocoding:
[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%2C+%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4+%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%2C+%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%2C+%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4+3&sensor=false](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%203&sensor=false)

Return

> ```
> {    "results" : [
>   {
>      "address_components" : [
>         {
>            "long_name" : "3",
>            "short_name" : "3",
>            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
>         },
>         {
>            "long_name" : "Lubyanskiy proyezd",
>            "short_name" : "Lubyanskiy pr-d",
>            "types" : [ "route" ]
>         },
>         {
>            "long_name" : "Tsentralnyy administrativnyy okrug",
>            "short_name" : "Tsentralnyy administrativnyy okrug",
>            "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
>         },
>         {
>            "long_name" : "Moskva",
>            "short_name" : "Moskva",
>            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
>         },
>         {
>            "long_name" : "gorod Moskva",
>            "short_name" : "g. Moskva",
>            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
>         },
>         {
>            "long_name" : "Moscow",
>            "short_name" : "Moscow",
>            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
>         },
>         {
>            "long_name" : "Russia",
>            "short_name" : "RU",
>            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
>         },
>         {
>            "long_name" : "101000",
>            "short_name" : "101000",
>            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
>         }
>      ],
>      "formatted_address" : "Lubyanskiy proyezd, 3, Moskva, Russia, 101000",
>      "geometry" : {
>         "bounds" : {
>            "northeast" : {
>               "lat" : 55.7587676,
>               "lng" : 37.6290579
>            },
>            "southwest" : {
>               "lat" : 55.7587612,
>               "lng" : 37.6290433
>            }
>         },
>         "location" : {
>            "lat" : 55.7587676,
>            "lng" : 37.6290579
>         },
>         "location_type" : "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
>         "viewport" : {
>            "northeast" : {
>               "lat" : 55.76011338029149,
>               "lng" : 37.6303995802915
>            },
>            "southwest" : {
>               "lat" : 55.75741541970849,
>               "lng" : 37.6277016197085
>            }
>         }
>      },
>      "place_id" : "EkbQm9GD0LHRj9C90YHQutC40Lkg0L_RgNC-0LXQt9C0LCAzLCDQnNC-0YHQutCy0LAsINCg0L7RgdGB0LjRjywgMTAxMDAw",
>      "types" : [ "street_address" ]
>   },
>   {
>      "address_components" : [
>         {
>            "long_name" : "3",
>            "short_name" : "3",
>            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
>         },
>         {
>            "long_name" : "Lubyanskiy proyezd",
>            "short_name" : "Lubyanskiy pr-d",
>            "types" : [ "route" ]
>         },
>         {
>            "long_name" : "Tsentralnyy administrativnyy okrug",
>            "short_name" : "Tsentralnyy administrativnyy okrug",
>            "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
>         },
>         {
>            "long_name" : "Moskva",
>            "short_name" : "Moskva",
>            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
>         },
>         {
>            "long_name" : "gorod Moskva",
>            "short_name" : "g. Moskva",
>            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
>         },
>         {
>            "long_name" : "Moscow",
>            "short_name" : "Moscow",
>            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
>         },
>         {
>            "long_name" : "Russia",
>            "short_name" : "RU",
>            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
>         },
>         {
>            "long_name" : "109074",
>            "short_name" : "109074",
>            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
>         }
>      ],
>      "formatted_address" : "Lubyanskiy proyezd, 3, Moskva, Russia, 109074",
>      "geometry" : {
>         "bounds" : {
>            "northeast" : {
>               "lat" : 55.7539059,
>               "lng" : 37.6355031
>            },
>            "southwest" : {
>               "lat" : 55.7538962,
>               "lng" : 37.6354968
>            }
>         },
>         "location" : {
>            "lat" : 55.7539059,
>            "lng" : 37.6354968
>         },
>         "location_type" : "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
>         "viewport" : {
>            "northeast" : {
>               "lat" : 55.7552500302915,
>               "lng" : 37.6368489302915
>            },
>            "southwest" : {
>               "lat" : 55.7525520697085,
>               "lng" : 37.6341509697085
>            }
>         }
>      },
>      "partial_match" : true,
>      "place_id" : "EkbQm9GD0LHRj9C90YHQutC40Lkg0L_RgNC-0LXQt9C0LCAzLCDQnNC-0YHQutCy0LAsINCg0L7RgdGB0LjRjywgMTA5MDc0",
>      "types" : [ "street_address" ]
>   }    ],    "status" : "OK" }
> ```

But I get incorrect result, when I try find place info by place_id from previos results.

For example:
Find place by place_id https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=EkbQm9GD0LHRj9C90YHQutC40Lkg0L_RgNC-0LXQt9C0LCAzLCDQnNC-0YHQutCy0LAsINCg0L7RgdGB0LjRjywgMTAxMDAw&key=YOUR_GOOGLE_GEO_API_KEY

Result:

> ```
> >     {    "html_attributions" : [],    "result" : {
> >       "address_components" : [
> >          {
> >             "long_name" : "3",
> >             "short_name" : "3",
> >             "types" : [ "street_number" ]
> >          },
> >          {
> >             "long_name" : "Lubyanskiy proyezd",
> >             "short_name" : "Lubyanskiy pr-d",
> >             "types" : [ "route" ]
> >          },
> >          {
> >             "long_name" : "Tsentralnyy administrativnyy okrug",
> >             "short_name" : "Tsentralnyy administrativnyy okrug",
> >             "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
> >          },
> >          {
> >             "long_name" : "Moskva",
> >             "short_name" : "Moskva",
> >             "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
> >          },
> >          {
> >             "long_name" : "gorod Moskva",
> >             "short_name" : "g. Moskva",
> >             "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
> >          },
> >          {
> >             "long_name" : "Moscow",
> >             "short_name" : "Moscow",
> >             "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
> >          },
> >          {
> >             "long_name" : "Russia",
> >             "short_name" : "RU",
> >             "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
> >          },
> >          {
> >             "long_name" : "101000",
> >             "short_name" : "101000",
> >             "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
> >          }
> >       ],
> >       "adr_address" : "\u003cspan class=\"street-address\"\u003eLubyanskiy proyezd, 3\u003c/span\u003e,
> > \u003cspan class=\"locality\"\u003eMoskva\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan
> > class=\"country-name\"\u003eRussia\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan
> > class=\"postal-code\"\u003e101000\u003c/span\u003e",
> >       "formatted_address" : "Lubyanskiy proyezd, 3, Moskva, Russia, 101000",
> >       "geometry" : {
> >          "location" : {
> >             "lat" : 55.7587676,
> >             "lng" : 37.6290579
> >          }
> >       },
> >       "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
> >       "id" : "38efff77618f372a66fe6aaadde36e46a8d9b0a8",
> >       "name" : "Lubyanskiy pr-d, 3",
> >       "place_id" : "Ej_Qm9GD0LHRj9C90YHQutC40Lkg0L_RgC4sIDMsINCc0L7RgdC60LLQsCwg0KDQvtGB0YHQuNGPLCAxMDEwMDA",
> >       "reference" : "CpQBiwAAAA6ClEFYu1E3xM-8kRNGEf0s6sLJTMfqfroDVdaujzEMomzMTJ7HB80Bb8X5JLNrChwXlcFyKs4Hxn1vwgBm4LBfyCgMLty6WewWGKg7MbJb7ZDBhK0kQMRTcbnPGQ7hAG5MNo9t8LIMfDu0kZmsoCosW1MDEHbiXIHC9uygPYplHN6VzNP71rjh8V0AbiaZ9BIQohpY3YsUs0bWEwDUr74NqRoUttzPvs4Mlv_1nLCiPb_yHz5hW5M",
> >       "scope" : "GOOGLE",
> >       "types" : [ "street_address" ],
> >       "url" : "https://maps.google.com/maps/place?q=Lubyanskiy+proyezd,+3,+Moskva,+Russia,+101000&ftid=0x46b54a5c1e406657:0xd25bbb02ec771347",
> >       "vicinity" : "Tsentralnyy administrativnyy okrug"    },    "status" : "OK" }
> ```

How can you see, the place_id is different in request and response.

> In request (last link): EkbQ......AxMDAw
>
> In response: Ej_Qm9.....MDEwMDA
>
> EkbQ......AxMDAw != Ej_Qm9.....MDEwMDA

The same place have two different place_id.

How can I solve this problemm?  I need help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Places API: Are “place_id” or “id” unique to any city in the world?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198283/google-places-api-are-place-id-or-id-unique-to-any-city-in-the-world)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, there is no problem to solve.  As @geocodezip says, a single location may have multiple place ID's.  Both of your place IDs are valid and stable and you can use either.  There are more details here: https://developers.google.com/places/place-id#multiple-ids

> When you request place details for a specific place ID, you receive
>   the details for the requested place. Note however that the place ID
>   may be different, if the place has received a new ID since your
>   previous request. You can safely continue to use the original place ID
>   to access the place, but it's recommended that you swap to using the
>   most recently-returned place ID whenever possible.

Answer (score 4):

The place_id is not unique.  The place is unique. There is nothing in the documentation that says there is a one-to-one mapping of place to place_id, only from place_id to place.  In fact the documentation specifically states that **a place can have multiple place IDs**.

[From the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#placeid)

> **Note:** Place IDs are also available through the Places API. A single place ID refers to only one place, but a place can have multiple place IDs. For more information, see the place ID overview.